# How to cleanup old wireless networks from the dropdown list

Tags: networking, wireless

Once when there was a very boring lecture at Uni, 300 students started making random networks. For some reason some of them stayed and are still there. I have never connected to them, and they are not under "Edit Connections".

Here is how they look like:

[image]

I want to remove the ones labeled "Heidi is a cool dog", "iPhone" and "GT-I9300". Those networks have not existed for at least for the past few months. At first I thought they would dissapear with the time, but seems like they wont.

Comment: I think those would show up under the Bluetooth menu in Settings. Have you checked there?

Comment: It worked? (Glad to help if it did) Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I will accept it

Comment: Short, but there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Bluetooth connections in Settings. That's what those are.